# Unique Values in NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, couchbase, database, nosql

Consider `mongodb` or `couchbase`. What if I need a certain value to be unique (maybe incremental) within the range of `UINT32`?

Well, I guess I could add a field like `another_id` and use something like [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) to increment it (mongo).

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}


db.users.insert(
   {
     another_id : getNextSequence("userid"),
     name       : "Stack O. Flow"
   }
)
```

But really the question is,

- Is this approach safe?
- Should I even use NoSQL for this? (consider I only have around 50M rows of data but I really need fast read and writes because this 50M rows of data gets updated almost a few times in second.)
- If I should stick with `SQL` which one should I use. I've used MySQL and it was too slow. (though non-optimization might be at fault) (joining quite a few tables)

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific counter object in Couchbase that should do what you want. Here is an [example of it with Node.js](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/sdks/node-2.0/atomic-operations.html).

You could relate it to the main object you are using by doing an objectID such as:

original_objectID::counter.

Then when you go to get the original object, you just do another get for the counter object by ID and done. You can iterate it easily as well. So if you needed to get the object and the original objectID was

user::kirk

then that user's counter object would be:

user::kirk::counter

And you can get and set it by that ID. It works very well in Couchbase.